# Numbers inside of a p tag not displaying correctly

Tags: css, html

I have zero idea why this is happening. I don't even know where to begin searching for this. I have two pictures from two different phones viewing the same webpage:

[Not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS5ry.png)

[Displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXiqf.jpg)

There is no difference between either pictures in terms of CSS or HTML.

```html
<h1>CONTACT US</h1>
<p style="color: #21584b !important;">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-30793" src="http://bosnianholidays.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/icon-footer-phone.png" alt="" width="24" height="24"> &nbsp;+387 33 761 600
</p>
<p style="color: #21584b !important;">
  <img class="size-full wp-image-30794 alignnone" src="http://bosnianholidays.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/icon-footer-whatsapp.png" alt="" width="24" height="24"> &nbsp;+387 65 991 111
</p>
<p style="color: #21584b !important;">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-30792" src="http://bosnianholidays.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/icon-footer-address.png" alt="" width="24" height="24"> Rustempašina 14 71 210 Ilidža Sarajevo, BiH<br>
</p>
```

Comment: It seems there's more CSS involved here... Are you sure you don't import another CSS code?

Comment: They *are* displaying, but written in white, which makes them almost invisible. Check your CSS if there is anything that might overrule your inline CSS (although with `!important` being used it's hard to imagine what that could be...)

Comment: I am thinking the "Not displaying" screenshot is a cached version of the page or it is before you applied the inline css

Answer (score 0):

The phone numbers in the "Not displaying" image are showing; they're just white. Look very closely and you'll see them. [image]

Comment: Oh... Thanks! But, still, why wouldn't they use the same color as the text(the green one)?

Comment: You'll need to include the code snippets behind both images. There _has_ to be a discrepancy. Without being able to view the code that is generating each of the images, everyone who tries to answer this question is going to be speculating. Once you get that up, I'll be more than happy to provide a suggestion as to what the issue is.

Comment: As mentioned by @Jonannes, you may need to Force Refresh in order to clear your browser cache.

Windows: ctrl + F5
Mac/Apple: Apple + R or command + R
Linux: F5

Since it looks like you're using Safari Mobile, http://refreshyourcache.com/en/safari-mobile/

Answer (score -1):

Press F12 if you are a windows user or just open the dev tools on your browser to  and inspect the element you want to change color , too see the final css being used by the element press on Computed (far right corner of the console ) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz3op.png

The other problem you are facing is the use of inline styles , these have different levels of precedence so its better you create classes in you css file

[1]: